# iOS: прокрутка/скрол таблицы UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

Какие есть способы прокручивать/скролить таблицу `UITableView` в самый верх, в самый низ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Скроллинг вверх

`UITableView` является наследником `UIScrollView`, поэтому к нему применимы следующие способы прокрутки.

**1) Указать нужное смещение.**

Objective-C:

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

**2) Указать видимую область.**

Objective-C:

```
[mainTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
mainTableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
```

---

Однако `UITableView` предоставляет собственные методы для движения по таблице с указанием индексов ячеек.

**3) Указать ячейку.**

Objective-C:

```
[mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                             animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
mainTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,
                atScrollPosition: .Top,
                animated: true)
```

---

## Скроллинг вниз

В целом, для прокрутки вниз применимы все те же методы, что и для перемещения вверх. Однако для методов `UIScrollView` по `Y` нужно указывать не ноль, а внутреннюю высоту таблицы, что бывает затруднительно рассчитать. Поэтому для решения этой задачи удобнее работать с методами `UITableView`.

**3) Указать ячейку.**

Objective-C:

```
[mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: rows_count-1 inSection:0]
               atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
               animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
var lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: rows_count-1, inSection: 0)
mainTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex,
                atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom,
                animated: true)
```

---

**1) Указать нужное смещение.**

Однако, можно указать координатой сдвига максимально возможное значение типа `float`, оно будет автоматически приведено к высоте содержимого.

Objective-C:

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                               animated: true)
```

---

*Использованные источники:*

- [enSU: scroll UITableView to the top, Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/724966/5308802)
- [enSU: scroll UITableView to the bottom, Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770189/5308802)
- [UIScrollView: scrollRectToVisible:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible?language=objc)
- [UITableView: scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorowatindexpath?language=objc)